# iOS JSONKit objectWithData returns null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, jsonkit

I'm using `JSONKit` to parse JSON strings, for some reason when trying to assign the JSON string into `NSDictionary` it returns null

```
JSONDecoder *jsonDecoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];        
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];
NSDictionary *tempDict = [jsonDecoder objectWithData:jsonData];
```

`jsonString` holds the content, tempDict equals `NULL`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some input that causes the issue? And just to verify, `jsonData` isn't `nil`, but `tempDict` is?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support 4.x don't use  `NSJSONSerialization`. It's only available in 5.0.

Instead you just need to use `JSONKit` like so:

```
 NSDictionary *tempDict = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

You don't need to convert your JSON string into NSData to serialize it.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure , but you need to check if your json is a valid json , for this you can use http://jsonlint.com/ . i faced this similar problem sometimes because of invalid json . hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why use jsonKit?
iOS has a very good JSONSerialization class... You can use it like this:

```
NSData *returnData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

NSDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

if (!jsonParsingError) {

    //Do your stuff here

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but NSJSONSerialization is available from iOS 5, I'm using JSONKit because it's support to prior iOS versions

Answer (score -1):

How about using NSJSONSerialization ?

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary * tempDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: using a different library is not a solution to the question.